# getting max array count

Tags: php, arrays

Hi need help getting repeated value from give array,below is the code which im trying get max values of `$values[4]`

```
$values = array(
    "0"=> "abc",
    "1"=> "aaa",
    "2"=> "aaa|abc",
    "3" =>  "| | | | | | | | | | | | | | | | ",
    "4" => "a|b|b|c|d|e|f|g",
    "5" => "1|2|3||4|5|6"
);


foreach ($values as $key) {
$prevalues = explode('|', $key);
$count[] = count($prevalues);
}
 print_r($counts);
 $counts = array_count_values($count);
 arsort($counts);
 echo $max= key($counts);


Array
 (
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 17
    [4] => 8
    [5] => 8
)
print_r($max );
```

Currently, I am getting $max = 1; I need $max to be 8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not:

```
foreach ($values as $key=>$value)
    $max = max(substr_count($value,'|')+1,$max);

echo $max;
```

No array splitting or storing arrays. :)

Comment: @user1477117 Is that a question?

Comment: @iambrainsreed : i need get the most repeated values in an array too,how can i get the repeated values using your method

Comment: what are the "most" repeated values? every value that is repeated inside one string? or just the top3?

Comment: @Mohammer count($values) which are repeated, in above array 8 repeated

Answer (score 1):

If you already have you array $counts with the values and you need only to find the max value in the array like i think you are asking, then there is a built in function for this already in php.

```
$max = max($counts);
```

$max will be equal to 17.

Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php

In regards to finding the must repeated value in the array as per your comment to iambrainsreed:

You could use array_count_values().

```
$valueCount = array_count_values($counts);
print_r($valueCount);
```

Would output:

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2
    [2] => 1
    [17] => 1
    [8] => 2 
)
```

From there you can use that data for what you need.
Documentation:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php

Comment: better yet, iambriansreed's idea to incorporate substr_count(),  you can get the documentation on that at. http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr-count.php

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()` to find the highest value in an array, here's an example

```
echo max(array(1, 5, 7, 2, 3));
```

This should give you `17`

```
foreach ($values as $item)
{
    $temp[] = substr_count($item, "|") + 1;
}

echo max($temp);
```

Comment: but i`m not able get max values from above code which im using

Answer (score 0):

You could probably use `substr_count($key,'|')+1` instead of `explode`.

**EDIT:** I am thinking that I don't really understand the question clearly, perhaps could you write more clearly? Why are you using the `key` function?